# Python joke or chat error

Tags: python

when i run this, if i type chat it runs the punchline from the joke above how do i fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oXAp.png)

```
print ("whats your name?")
firstname = input()
print ("hello,", firstname)
print ("what's your surname?")
surname = input()

fullname = (firstname +" "+ surname)
print ("hello,", fullname)

print ("what shall i call you on a daily basis?")
name = input()
print ("Glad to meet you,", name)


print ("is there anything you would like to do?")
print (" you can 'hear a joke' or 'have a chat'")


question = input("joke or chat?")
if question == "joke":
 print("what do you call a deer with no heart?")
idk = input()
print ("Dead!!! LOL!!!!")

if question == "chat":
 print("what games do you like?")
game = input()
print ("NO way i love,", game)
```

Comment: It looks like it's doing what its supposed to do, but I'm surprised it even runs with that indenting. Indent blocks correctly as python has no braces.

Comment: Which version of python?

Answer (score 1):

Your spacing / indentation is off:

```
if question == "joke":
 print("what do you call a deer with no heart?")
idk = input()
print ("Dead!!! LOL!!!!")
```

In your code should be:

```
if question == "joke":
 print("what do you call a deer with no heart?")
 idk = input()
 print ("Dead!!! LOL!!!!")
```

**PS:** You should use more than 1 space for indenting to make it easier to read. Such as:

```
if question == "joke":
    print("what do you call a deer with no heart?")
    idk = input()
    print ("Dead!!! LOL!!!!")
```

Comment: Python suggests to use 4 spaces for indentation.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of proper indentation, Python is assuming that the lines

```
idk = input()
print ("Dead!!! LOL!!!!")
```

are outside the `if` statement. Indent them like you did for the `print` statement for the punchline.